# Unsupported project that is a folder

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I Have recently upgraded my old Visual Studio 2008 project to 2012.

I now have an error "Error  1   The project 'Add-in Projects' is unsupported        0   0".

The Add-ins Projects isn't a project it is just a folder in the solution that contains projects. All of the projects compile fine without any issues.

All of the solutions for unsupported projects don't seem to apply as it is simply a folder.

It doesn't actually effect any of the projects they all compile fine and seem to work fine, its just slightly annoying.

Has anyone encountered this before and could suggest how i might fix this error?

Cheers

Comment: I encountered it in VS2013. I don't know how to fix it. Includes folders like .nuget